# Automake adding flags to install.sh

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am using autotools to build some packages that I want the headers to be installed only if they are changed.

I see that `install.sh` has a flag `-C` for installing only if different, but how do i set that flag in autotools?

In my Makefile.am I am providing nobase_libhello_include_HEADERS = file1.h file2.h if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You override the install command when calling `configure`:

```
./configure INSTALL="/usr/bin/install -C"
```

Comment: This is a workable solution but you have to remember to do it every time you run configure. Would be nice if there was a way to tell automake what install options to use directly.